# What is the way to use FTP and Notepad++ (without using its build-in FTP or a FTP client like FileZilla)?

Tags: ftp, notepad++

I use Notepad++ for more than 2 years now, and there's only 1 thing that it needs for me to be perfect: a actually-working-ftp-plugin.

It has an FTP plugin, written by someone that meanwhile left the project (by meanwhile I mean a long time ago), and since then nobody had courage to improve it. The problem is that it does't handle connections very well. Sometimes it lost connection with the server and literally "blocks", others don't save the files properly, other only load half of the FTP files, etc etc ..

My question is: Is there a way to use FTP and Notepad++ (without using its build-in FTP or a FTP client like FileZilla)?

I've tried using NetDrive, but it gets stuck sometimes (makes the editor crash), and everytime the temporary file is refreshed by windows / NetDrive, it will load the new file without asking and skip the pointer to the end of the file (very very very annoying).

In case you know how to make the built-in notepad++ ftp plugin work at 100%, I'd be much more happy!

I'd like to have some feedback from you guys :)

(I'm using Windows Vista)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here is my *"Notepad++ FTP best solution"*
I use WinSCP and set NP++ as a default editor. When I open a connection in WinSCP, select a file and hit F4 the file is opened in WINDOWS\Temp with NP++, when I save that file WinSCP automatically uploads it back to server. Works like a charm! WinSCP is the most stable thing I ever tried, it never looses a connection.
FTP_synchronize sucks. Manual upload is not handy. So WinSCP+NP++ is the best solution.
Give it a try.

Answer (score 6):

I use [**FTP Synchronize**](http://cid-89e56cb76c1eea71.skydrive.live.com/self.aspx/.Public/FTP|_synchronize.rar). It automatically updates the FTP server when you save, so you can save then instantly refresh your browser if working on web content. There is also [**FTPExplorer**](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ftpexplorerplug/files/) which acts like an explorer window with FTP functionality from within Notepad++.

Comment: What OS do you use? Did you ever had problems with FTP Synchronize? Also, FTPExplorer from the link you provided only have the files before compilation.

Comment: FTP Sync. isn't perfect, but it's fairly close. I've lost files with it before, so be careful with your backups (I say lost, it was thankfully still in my cache, but it was a lesson)

Comment: That's exacly that "perfection" that is missing. I loose many files, and get many problems with it. What I want to know is a way to have a ftp plugin / other sollution that works fine. If that implies changing OS, so be it (I'm using VIsta by the way)

Comment: I'm on Vista too, and my problems are very rare. Perhaps it's a settings thing, have you tried running portable npad++ with it for a while?

Comment: No, but I'll try it out and leave feedback latter.

Comment: Didn't took much time. One of the portable versions of Notepad++ doesn't even works, and the other doesn't let me use FTP Sync.

Answer (score 1):

Does it have to be built into Notepad++?  If no, I'd check out [ExpanDrive](http://www.expandrive.com/windows).

Comment: Does that software creates temp files when editting them remotelly? If so, it will generate the same issues I mentioned in the question.

Comment: I don't know, I haven't used it.  It's a free trial though!

Answer (score 1):

### Other Answers:

Here are a couple of answers that other people posted to [a duplicate of this question](https://superuser.com/q/242874/150988):

---

> For Displaying a Local Tree I use the [Light Explorer](http://sourceforge.net/projects/npp-plugins/files/LightExplorer/LightExplorer%202.0%20UNICODE) plugin.
>
> I haven't used nppFTP much, but just giving it a try you can set up a local/remote cache map, so whenever you save a file in the local directory it will upload it to the remote directory.
>
> answered Feb 7 '11 at 23:46
>                                                                   by [Ben](https://superuser.com/users/71730/ben)
>                                                                   [image: Ben’s user card]

---

> This video explains in detail how to do this:
>   [HOW-TO Use Notepad++ and FTP](http://vimeo.com/51823904)
>
> Video by Jimmynewland.
>
> This article can help: [access FTP Server using Notepad++](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/access-ftp-server-notepad)
>
> Using its *[NppFTP plug-in](http://sourceforge.net/projects/npp-plugins/files/FTP_synchronize)*.
>
> answered Jun 1 '13 at 04:08
>                                                                   by [Tiago CA](https://superuser.com/users/219655/tiago-ca)
>                                                                   [image: Tiago CA’s user card]

Answer (score 0):

To work with FTP plugin on Notepad++. You've to : *Disable IPv6, and have to check if your LAN Adapter driver is not enabled "Priority & VLAN"*. If it's Enabled by default on Win7, you've to disable it.

If you don't find it working still with this then use [FTPExplorer](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ftpexplorerplug/files/).

Comment: Doing what you suggest didn't worked at all. FTPExplorer isn't compiled, how do I use it?

Comment: Extract it in plugins folder. Restart NP++.

Comment: Doesn't work. The files provided are code files (c++). NP++ needs at least 1 .dll in order to work. The actually plugin listen in sourceforge isn't compiled at all. I've tried to compile it, but the files aren't in the correct place (so the makefile could find them) and there were some files missing, what makes me think that the plugin isn't prepared to be installed at all. Anyone was able to put it to work properly?

Answer (score 0):

I use [FileZilla](http://filezilla-project.org/) for FTP. You'd be hard-pressed to find any plugin that beats it.

You can kind of "synchronize" with Notepad++ by setting it as the default editor in the settings then doing right click > edit on the server-side panel.

Comment: I've use it for many months. The problem is that I have to either open Filezilla window to press upload so the modified file can be uploaded, or use scripts that bypass that question (but still got to open the filezilla window). As a full time coder, I don't have time to do such thing, and need to have my files uploaded as soon as I press "save" on Notepad++.

Comment: Unfortunatelly, FileZilla is reported to be a crapware now..

Comment: @YannisDran How so?

Comment: @DisgruntledGoat all the past years I was using it, but there were reports of such a thing. Don't get confused and think that I meant the bundled version. Anyway, I haven't evaluated it thoroughly yet, but I think WinSCP is a good alternative. As hard as it was to believe that FZ was unbeatable, now it all seems as a mater of brain focus.