# Notepad++ and FTP

Tags: ftp, plugins, notepad++

I've been using [UltraEdit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UltraEdit) for several years now, but after upgrading to Windows 7, I decided to try out [Notepad++](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notepad%2B%2B) instead.  It seems pretty similar and pretty powerful, but one of the best features of UltraEdit was the built in FTP client.  Everything I've seen by googling says FTP Synchronizer is a built-in plugin that has this functionality.

I do not see this plugin anywhere, in the list of available or installed plugins, nor anywhere I can find in the program.  Has it been removed and all these articles are just outdated?

Alternatively, I found [FTPExplorer](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ftpexplorerplug/files/) which sounds like a more robust FTP/file management tool, but the only download I could find is uncompiled source code, and I don't know how to compile them / install them.  Any thoughts?

I found [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/47497/notepad-ftp-best-solution) however there never was a real answer to the question, I can't/don't want to disable IPv6, and as mentioned above I still don't know how to install FTPExplorer.

**Please Note:** I do not need suggestions for other FTP programs, nor ways of making Notepad++ work with external FTP clients better.

Comment: Thanks for posting this!

I use Notepad++ and think it's awesome but hadn't realized it did FTP. Awesome!

Comment: http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/notepad-plus/index.php?title=Plugin_Central

Is a good place for plugins, I suggest the autosave plugin and the explorer plugin as the most useful and time saveing. Also take a look at the keyboard shortcuts page, if you learn these, your productivity will be greatly increased.

http://notepad-plus.sourceforge.net/uk/shortcuts.php

Comment: FTPExplorer has only been downloaded 85 times from SourceForge, though it has 5 stars. The download is a zip-file with only source code, and not even a readme-file. So judging from the cover (since looking inside the book would require compiling!) it most likely is a scrappy beta, and not worth experimenting with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ultimately I gave up on Notepad++.  If you use it and find it works for you, grand, but after giving it a whirl I'm going to stick with UltraEdit, and I'd recommend it to anyone considering Notepad++.

Answer (score 6):

Link for the [FTP Synchronize Plugin](http://sourceforge.net/projects/npp-plugins/files/FTP_synchronize/) for Notepad++.

Comment: The last version was in 2008, which is a bad sign, however it is still downloaded more than 100times per week as of 2013.

Answer (score 4):

I know you don't want to use another client, but hear me out.

I use WinSCP as my FTP/SFTP client and I have grown to love it. I set the "default" editor to Notepad++ and it works great. I get the familiarity of Windows explorer and ability to use Notepad++. Basically, once you setup WinSCP to use Notepad++ as the default editor, you just double click a file on the server, it will open Notepad++ and work like you would normally - though when you save - WinSCP will automatically upload the changed file (or new file you create). WinSCP is free and open source, so there is no reason to at least try it out.

To be honest, I find the FTP plugin for Notepad++ to be clunky and not useful at all.

You can vote me down, but I feel that its a lot better to separate the 2 "features". I used Dreamweaver back in the day with the FTP integration and was not impressed at all.

Now, if you are using a Linux box then you should just mount the FTP server using curlftpfs and forget about FTP clients!

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to FTP Synchronize is NppFTP: http://sourceforge.net/projects/nppftp/
It does the job unless you need to configure a proxy

Answer (score 0):

For me, FTP-synchronize shows up under Plugins -> FTP_Synchronize ( running on Unicode edition, Notepad++ 5.4.5 ). Else you can pick it up from [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/npp-plugins/files/FTP_synchronize/).

Answer (score 0):

I also switched to UltraEdit. I was using N++ for couple months but now I urgently need FTP access from the editor. FTP_Synchronize barely works and FTPExplorer plugin is in uncompiled version so it's useless for me. I think that N++ has some wasted potential...

Answer (score 0):

[PSPAD](http://www.pspad.com/) has all you want: great editor and FTP native support and it works great.