# FTP and Notepad++

Tags: plugins, ftp, notepad++

I've been using UltraEdit for several years now, but after upgrading to Windows 7, I decided to try out Notepad++ instead.  It seems pretty similar and pretty powerful, but one of the best features of UltraEdit was the built in FTP client.  Everything I've seen by googling says FTP Synchronizer is a built in plugin that has this functionality.

I do not see this plugin anywhere, in the list of available or installed plugins, nor anywhere I can find in the program.  Has it been removed and all these articles are just outdated?

Alternatively, I found [FTPExplorer](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ftpexplorerplug/files/) which sounds like a more robust FTP/File management tool, but the only download I could find is uncompiled source code, and I don't know how to compile them / install them.  Any thoughts?

Comment: I'm sure I've seen a question very similar to this somewhere.

Comment: I found this earlier: http://superuser.com/questions/47497/notepad-ftp-best-solution but I need IPv6, and the other half of the accepted solution is use FTPExplorer, which is what I'm asking how to install.

Answer (score 10):

Just as a note, aside from a possible NotePad++ plugin, I use [WinSCP](http://winscp.net/eng/docs/introduction) + Notepad++. WinSCP allows me to add Notepad++ as an external editor, then I can open the remote files in Notepad++, edit them, and save them and the changes are uploaded seamlessly. This gives me the FTP power of a dedicated application (*With nice UI, navigation, bookmarking, and other features*), while leveraging the editing power of a dedicated editor (Rather than a shoddy built-in editor which most FTP clients have).

WinSCP is open source and supports FTP/SFTP/SCP. It's a nice app.

Sorry if I misunderstood your question.

**EDIT**: It seems that Notepadd++ already supports FTP, which would explain why that plugin hasn't been updated since 2007. Take a look at [this article](http://www.pcmech.com/article/edit-files-live-via-ftp-with-notepad-how-to/) which is a walkthrough of the feature. Hope that helps!

Comment: Yes, I've used WinSCP, FileZilla, and several other FTP clients.  They work fine for FTP, but do not provide the feature I'm looking for, since they require working with two different programs at once.  As best I can tell, Notepad++ has this functionality, but I can't figure out how to set it up, and that is what I am asking about.

Comment: Ah okay, sorry then. I've personally had better experiences having separated dedicated apps than one good app which has clunky support for feature x just for the sake of having it. I looked through the archive of the plugin and there's a release folder in there but nothing in it, so yeah you'd have to build it yourself somehow (no instructions are given). Best bet would be to contact the author I imagine.

Comment: That plugin hasn't been updated since 2007 either, unless it changed it's name and repository (that's a possibility). Guess you should look for an alternative solution, or give WinSCP (or any other FTP client which supports external editors) another try.

Comment: Take a look at my new edit, looks like Notepad already supports FTP, but it's easy to miss the icon which triggers it.

Comment: Yes, I found that article earlier, but that button does not exist in my install (possibly because I'm using Windows 7? - I don't know) or is in a different place and I can't find it.  In any case, I've also been trying to find some other tool, notice the FTPExplorer plugin, which as I understand it is more robust that the built in one anyways - but I can't figure out how to install it into Notepad++.

Answer (score 0):

You can try NPPFTP Plugin. Here is its website:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/nppftp/

It allows you to access your ftp sites right from Notepad++.