# How to Use Notepad++ FTP?

Tags: plugins, ftp, notepad++

I'm trying to find a new code editor, have gone through several, and am now using Notepad++, which I hear is a favorite of developers. My problem is that while I see that Notepad++ has FTP, as far as I can tell I can only access remote servers. Does Notepad++ have the ability to display a local directory tree? And is it possible to synchronize local and remote directories? I know Notepad++ has a lot of plug-ins but the documentation is kind of hard to understand, and I'm a n00b.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For Displaying a Local Tree I use the [Light Explorer](http://sourceforge.net/projects/npp-plugins/files/LightExplorer/LightExplorer%202.0%20UNICODE/) plugin.

I haven't used nppFTP much, but just giving it a try you can set up a local/remote cache map, so whenever you save a file in the local directory it will upload it to the remote directory.

Answer (score 0):

This video explains in detail how to do this:

[HOW-TO Use Notepad++ and FTP](http://vimeo.com/51823904)

Video by Jimmynewland.

This article can help: [access FTP Server using Notepad++](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/access-ftp-server-notepad)

Using its *[NppFTP plug-in](http://sourceforge.net/projects/npp-plugins/files/FTP_synchronize/)*.